# jQuery hover() only triggers when mouse move

Tags: jquery

I have a button that changes opacity when it is hovered: *(works fine)*

```
$('#btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({'opacity':1},100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({'opacity':.8},100);
});
```

And when it is pressed it moves down: *(works fine too)*

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({'margin-top':'-100px'},400);
});
```

Problem: When the button moves, it moves away from the hover area, **but** the first hover state is still active (the first hover state should only be active when the mouse is hovered over the button). However, if I move the mouse from there on, the second state triggers as jquery notice that mouse moves.

Is there any way for hover() to trigger even if mouse is not moved?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery.animate instead of CSS transitions?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I think the right tool for this job is CSS

Comment: @connexo Because css transitions 1) delayed animate() and also 2) using css gave me the exact same problem.

Comment: @frenchie Tried with css too and the same problem: only triggers when mouse moves.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this).trigger("mouseout")`

This will cause the correct `hover()` handler to fire.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/va87ff96/

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, the problem is that the hover state is still active, after moving.

Then why not add the opacity to the animation too?

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity':.8,'margin-top':'-100px'},400);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6v29ok5/)

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I prefer the answer above a bit more since its more fancy.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you on that one :)